# Modify a Sharepoint App

Tags: document-library, document-template

I created a SharePoint App based on a document library (with content). How do I edit that app? By that I mean the folders within that app etc? Or do I have to create it again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify a document library by going to the Library Settings. You can access Library Settings in the Library tab of the ribbon or by clicking the gear icon if you are using Modern Lists in SharePoint Online.